# I want to print (3D) a blender object, that I edited in sculpt mode. All changes disappear exporting it to stl

Tags: 3d-printing, stl, sculpt-mode, blender-osm

I use blender 4.0 to design objects, I want to print. As the sculpt mode offers lots of very nice tools, I tried to use it. But when I exported the object (to stl), all changes I had done in sculpt mode disappeared, only the mesh I started with was exported.
I´ve already tried to ask bing for help. It explains me to convert the object to a mesh. That doesnt work out too. all changes dissappeare. Same goes for export to obj.

Does somebody know what I´m doing wrong? Or what I need to do to print the object I´ve designed?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sculpting *only* works on meshes, so if you have done sculpting, you already had a mesh in your hand, so Bing was wrong. What you explain sounds to me like you had a `Multi Resolution` modifier in your modifier stack and when exporting you didn't check the option `Apply Modifiers` in the export panel.

Comment: Oh, Your´re right, I use the modifier Multiresolution. Luckily the checkbox was selected automatically. However, its not working...

Comment: you probably have to make sure that your viewport levels are set up correctly (to your desired detail level) when exporting. may you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Oh wow, it works! Thank you so much!!! You were right, the viewport level was set to 0. Now its exporting correctly and I can also see the changes in `ObjectMode` . Perfect!